# How to verify if my JDBC query output has data in it or not

Tags: jdbc

I want to verify if my JDBC query output has data in it or not. If it doesn't contain any data then it should print the assertion as false.

I tried using this:

```
System.out.println("Table contains "+rs.getRow()+" rows");
```

```
if (!rs.next())
{
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
else
{
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

I tried using as below:

```
System.out.println("Table contains "+rs.getRow()+" rows");

if (!rs.next())
{
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
else
{
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
```

But it didn't work. So can anyone suggest how to solve this?

Comment: "But it didn't work" - can you explain why? What output did you expect from it, and what was the actual output it gave you?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know, how many rows are in a table, let the DBMS count them with:

```
select count(*) as noRows from table
```

And within your java code it will look like this snippet

```
boolean hasRows= false;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs   = null;
try {
   stmt = connection.createStatement();
   rs   = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) as noRows from table");
   if ( rs.next() ) {
      if ( rs.getInt(1) > 0 ) {
          hasRows = true;
     }
   }
} catch (SQLException sqlex ) {
   // print or log an error message
} finally {
   if ( rs != null ) {
     try { 
        rs.close();
     } catch (SQlException sqlex ) {
        // print or log an error message
     }
   }
   if ( stmt != null ) {
     try { 
        stmt.close();
     } catch (SQlException sqlex ) {
        // print or log an error message
     }
   }
}
Assert.assertTrue(hasRows);
```

And it could also make sense to close your connection.
This will just return the rows within a table. If you need to know the size of a particular query, I for myself would do it similarly with the query and just replace the fields from the query with the count(*) or count(DISTINCT xyz) command. Try it first out within your sql monitor, because if the query runs to long, you might not be happy.